# Como controlar la forma en que se carga las fuentes en el navegador?

Tags: html, css, font-faces

Estoy presentando un problema con la forma en que se cargan las fuentes en mi navegador, estoy haciendo haciendo uso de `@font-face` para agregar una fuente personalizada a mi sitio web pero esto hace que se vea mi fuente anterior y rápidamente se cambia a la actual que uso en `@font-face`, es cuestion se milisegundos pero es un cambio notable al estar navegando dentro de la pagina.

Existe alguna forma de cambiar el modo en como se carga la fuente, el siguiente es el pequeño fragmento de código que uso de `@font-face`.

```
@font-face {
            font-family: "Lettera Text Std";
            src: url("Font/LetteraTextStd.woff2") format('woff2'), 
                url("Font/LetteraTextStd.woff") format('woff'), 
                url("Font/LetteraTextStd.ttf") format('truetype'), 
                url("Font/LetteraTextStd.svg") format('svg'), 
                url("Font/LetteraTextStd-Títulos.otf") format('embedded-opentype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
            font-display: swap;
        }
```

Lo anterior me sucede en los 3 navegadores Chrome, Firefox y Edge.